# Tomcat is not configuring in ubuntu server from command line putty

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ubuntu, solr

I want to run tomcat server on my ubuntu server
i am using putty to use command line. I want to run tomcat, java and solr search on my ubuntu matchine
after configuring my website should run apache tomcate like this 
http://mydomain.com:8080/solr/
but I am unable to configure this
I also changed port name for this.

I am getting an error of

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
May 06, 2014 11:33:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance inproduction environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
May 06, 2014 11:33:35 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 06, 2014 11:33:35 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 06, 2014 11:33:35 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1874 ms
May 06, 2014 11:33:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 06, 2014 11:33:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.53
May 06, 2014 11:33:35 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/docs
May 06, 2014 11:33:51 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG]     took [14,498] milliseconds.
May 06, 2014 11:33:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/host-manager
May 06, 2014 11:33:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/manager
May 06, 2014 11:33:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/examples
May 06, 2014 11:33:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
May 06, 2014 11:33:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 06, 2014 11:33:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 06, 2014 11:33:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 18260 ms
May 06, 2014 11:33:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:723)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)

May 06, 2014 11:33:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 06, 2014 11:33:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 06, 2014 11:33:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
May 06, 2014 11:33:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 06, 2014 11:33:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 06, 2014 11:33:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 06, 2014 11:33:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

I am getting this error shown below

ava.net.BindException: Address already in use:8080 error

even I changed the port no in

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

...

thanks in advance

Comment: `SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use`. Port 8005 seems to be in use?

Comment: yes it is already in use, I have change all the port and its working now